# derivative of an element of array

Tags: derivatives

I have an array $V_{N*K}$ that I have a function defined over the elements of this matrix which is

$$
F=\sum_{j}^N\sum_{l}^N\sum_{k}^KV_{jk}\log\frac{V_{jk}}{V_{lk}}+V_{lk}\log\frac{V_{lk}}{V_{jk}}
$$

The question is what is the derivative of this function, $F$ with respect to an element of array $V$, i.e., $V_{jk}$

Answer (score 0):

The rules of derivatives do not change.

$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial V_{jk}}=\sum_j^N\sum_l^N\sum_k^K \log\frac{V_{jk}}{V_{lk}}+1-\frac{V_{lk}}{V_{jk}}
$$

Comment: Do you mean that for instance $$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial V_{1,1}}=\sum_{l}^N\log\frac{V_{1,1}}{V_{l,1}}+1-\frac{V_{l,1}}{V_{1,1}}
$$ what happens if the sum of each row of $V$ is equal to 1. Then what would be your solution? Thanks